# Search button with image in background height inconsistencies

Tags: html, css

I made a search bar with a button that has an image as a background. I really can't get the button and the search bar to be the same height on all the browsers and devices.

My HMTL:

```
<form action="test.php">
                            <input type="search" placeholder="Indiquer un département...">
                            <input type="image" name="search" src="./img/loupe.png">
                        </form>
```

My CSS:

```
    .search form input[type=search] {
    position: relative;
    left: 1.8em;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 0.87em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    -webkit-appearance: none
}

.search form input[type=search]:hover {
    border: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
}

.search form input[type="image"] {
    height: 1.96em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5em 20px;
    left: 1.8em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    background-color: #4689f5;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px #2f78eb solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.search form input[type="image"]:hover {
    background-color: #367ae8;
    border: 1px #2d59b5 solid;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If it's a matter of device resolutions, use `media queries` to style your elements

Comment: Thanks it's a little bit better, I will keep it lie this it's not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try `vertical-align: middle` in your `input[type="image"]`.